# How do I include javascript files server-side?

Tags: javascript, server-side

I want to include JS file inside another JS file, on server side, to prevent copy-paste and multiple JS files loading from client.
Just like include('file.js') as PHP would do.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I just want it to be done on server, with one single javascript file load from client. I'd rather turn .js into .php (or rewrite) and use PHP include and then header('content-type:text/javascript). Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Supercharging javascript](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript-part-1-make-as.html) article suggest - with PHP you can read all your .js files and create one big js file that you will send in one piece.

This is a simplification of the example from the article, just to get you started:

```
<?php 
define('SCRIPT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/script/');

$files = array(
    'jquery.js',
    'myLib.js',
    'site.js'
);

header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
foreach (files as $file) {
    if (@readfile(SCRIPT_DIR . $file) === false) {
        error_log("javascript.php: Error reading file '$file'");
    }
}
?>
```

I would also recommend to read the full article [Supercharging JavaScript in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript.html) to get more info.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm just thinking about. I dont need a library for that. I can just do it myself in a few line of codes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to include other JavaScript files from a JavaScript file ... but you can add them into the DOM ->

```
function addJavascript(jsname,pos) {
  var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
  th.appendChild(s);
}
```

Example usage :

```
addJavascript('newExternal.js','body');
```

Comment: I will certainly vote this up for the cute code, but better handle path problems, order of script loads and dependency management to a script loader :)

Answer (score 1):

JSfile = "1.js, 2.js, 3.js"

for loop it

document.write();

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a **script loader** and i would like to recommend `script.js` by Dustin Diaz who works at Twitter. [Project Page on Github](https://github.com/ded/script.js).
Here is how you use it
assuming you have a jquery plugin to be loaded in a page here is what you should do

```
// load jquery and plugin at the same time. name it 'bundle'
$script(['jquery.js', 'my-jquery-plugin.js'], 'bundle')

// load your usage
$script('my-app-that-uses-plugin.js')


/*--- in my-jquery-plugin.js ---*/
$script.ready('bundle', function() {
  // jquery & plugin (this file) are both ready
  // plugin code...
})


/*--- in my-app-that-uses-plugin.js ---*/
$script.ready('bundle', function() {
  // use your plugin :)
})
```

example is also from project page. Here are steps you should follow

1. Load the Script.js file first
2. Now include the dependency loader script that loads all the other wanted scripts async[the content of dependency loader script would be like above]